# NSUserDefaults is empty

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save some data in NSUserDefaults in application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method in UIApplicationDelegate, and then read this data in viewDidLoad: in my main view controller. However, the data is always empty!

If I save the same data in viewDidLoad: in the main view controller, it's immediately visible and recoverable, but it's not when I save it in UIApplicationDelegate.

Any idea of this behavior? Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
    {
        // Save my data
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setURL:url forKey:@"url"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        return YES;
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    // It's always false !! 
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] URLforKey:@"url"] != nil){
        // Do something with url
        }
}
```

Comment: check if `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
` delegate is invoking or not. That delegate will invoked only if it is launched using URL schema.

Comment: @Till. No. I have commented on this question. I am asking whether the delegate he implemented is invoking or not.

Comment: Is that saving ever invoked? Add an NSLog.

Comment: Yes, it's invoking that method. If I run the app twice, then it works because the "url" key is properly saved... why the main view controller isn't able to see this key the first time? thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problema was that viewDidLoad: in my main view controller is called before than application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:, so there isn't any value stored yet.

I must check the NSUserDefaults in other place.

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: This strange behaviour was because I didn't use storyboard and I created my own nib files, loading them in a wrong way from my UIApplication delegate.

Answer (score -3):

In your code you have programmed NSUrl in NSUserDefault. Try with NSString. (i.e. [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]) .

So it would be  `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] forKey:@"url"];`

Comment: the method is called [`setURL:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-SW36) for a reason. If it would be for `NSStrings` it would be called `setString:forKey:`

Comment: ohh!1 I'm sorry. I wanted to write setvalue. Now I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Foram.. `setURL:` is not `NSString`, it is `NSURL`. Please verify before answering to a question